# How to import csv whose time data is in the format of “M-d-y h-m”?

Tags: python, dolphindb

The sample data from csv is shown as follows:

| datetime | symbol | price | volume |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10/1/2020 9:00 | XYZ | 10.68 | 375 |
| 10/1/2020 9:00 | XYZ | 10.9 | 66 |
| 10/1/2020 9:00 | XYZ | 11.42 | 103 |
| 10/1/2020 9:00 | XYZ | 12.62 | 280 |
| 10/1/2020 9:00 | XYZ | 10.73 | 23 |
| 10/1/2020 9:00 | XYZ | 11.44 | 299 |

I executed the following line to read the data:

```py
schemaTB = extractTextSchema(csvFile)
update schemaTB set type="DATETIME" where name="datetime"
schemaTB[`format]=["M-d-y h:m:s",,,];
t = loadText(csvFile,,schemaTB)
```

But it report an error:

```py
t = loadText(csvFile, , schemaTB) => Invalid temporal format M-d-y h:m:s
```

Comment: You're specifying `M-d-y` but the date appears to be in `MM/DD/YYYY` format (or something like that). The separator, at least, is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking of a couple of options here, perhaps opening it with `pandas` and parsing it to datetime and uploading the dataframe?
Another option would be manipulating the text into the standard dolphinDB (which is different from pandas) please refer here [6.3.2 Data type conversion](https://github.com/dolphindb/Tutorials_EN/blob/master/python_api.md) for more information about it

for example:

```
import dolphindb as ddb
import pandas as pd
s = ddb.session()
s.connect(host, port, "admin", "123456")
t = pd.read_csv('path_to_csv_file')
t['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(t['datetime'],infer_datetime_format=True)
s.upload({'t':t})
```

Answer (score 0):

The revised code would look like this

```py
schemaTB = extractTextSchema(csvFile)
update schemaTB set type="DATETIME" where name="datetime"
schemaTB[`format]=["MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm",,,];
t = loadText(csvFile,,schemaTB)
```

For more information, please refer to section 2 and 4
in [import_csv tutorial](https://github.com/dolphindb/Tutorials_EN/blob/master/import_csv.md)